# Image file getting corrupted on uploading to amazon s3 public bucket using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image using reactjs but the image is getting corrupted on upload to amazon s3.
The code is as follows.

```
uploadToS3 = (imageUri, fileName, fileType, file,success, failure) => {
    let body    = new FormData();
    let url=imageServer+fileName;
    body.append('key', fileName);
    body.append('acl', 'public-read');
    body.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    body.append('Content-Disposition', 'inline');
    body.append('file', {
      name: 'file',
      uri: imageUri,
      type: file.type
    });
    return axios.post(imageServer,body,
    { headers: {
        'Accept':file.type,
        'Content-Type':file.type,
      }}
    ).then(response => {
      console.log('[AWS S3] Response ==> ', response)
      this.props.addNewImage(url,this.props.arrayname);
      return response;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('[AWS S3] Error ==> ', error)
      return error;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Is the file named correctly when it gets to S3? Is it larger or smaller when it gets to S3?

Comment: @KMo yes the file is named absolutely correctly when i see in the amazon s3.But its corrupted!!please help!

Comment: What's the difference in file size between what you want to send and what is in S3?

Comment: File size there is only 15bytes whereas the actual size is much larger

Comment: Looks like you are not actually uploading your file properly as part of 'body'. Are you testing this from a web browser? You could check in developer tools to see what payload you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the mistake which I was making was sending the wrong value for 'file' object in formData object.The correct code is as follows-

```
uploadToS3 = (imageUri, fileName, fileType, file,success, failure) => {
    let body    = new FormData();
    let url=imageServer+fileName;
    body.append('acl', 'public-read');
    body.append('Content-Type',file.type);
    body.append('key', fileName);
    body.append('file',file);

   return axios.post(imageServer,body)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('[AWS S3] Response ==> ', response)
      this.props.addNewImage(url,this.props.arrayname);
      return response;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('[AWS S3] Error ==> ', error)
      return error;
    })
  }


_handleImageChange(e){
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file,'file');
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      let uri=reader.result;
      let fileType = /^data:image\/\w+;/.exec(reader.result)[0].replace(/^data:image/,"").replace("/","").replace(";","");
      let fileName='img'+`${new Date().getTime()}`+'.'+fileType;
      console.log("filename",fileName);
      this.uploadToS3(uri,fileName,fileType,file);     
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```