# Broken file upload with React to AWS S3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch

I've already tried multiple code for uploading, from axios to fetch. But, it always end up with same result. Here's the simplest it get:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', ref)

    const response = await fetch(
      new Request(res.uploadSignedUrl, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: formData,
        headers: new Headers({
          'Content-Type': ref.type,
        })
      })
    )
```

The code above is responding with status 200, but whenever I visit the image link of the uploaded image, it gives me a small white box image.

[screenshot of small white box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amkms.png)

And when I remove the header at 2nd parameter object of request fetch, the Content-Type to be specific, the link of the uploaded image doesn't transfer me to a website or anything. It just automatically downloads an unknown file type with surprisingly the exact file size of the supposed to be uploaded image.

[screenshot of automatic download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b43E.png)

Do note that I've already tried this with multiple file types. Any given thoughts about this issue will be deeply appreciated.

Edit: Also, I managed to come in contact with our backend dev. Here's the result at postman I think: [screenshot of payload result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9xYS.png)

ANSWER: I commented it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

from reddit user u/Wombarly,

> You're uploading the form data instead of the actual image. So you
> have to get the image blob and upload it instead.
>
> The form data adds the WebkitDisposition bit at the top of the payload
> in the screenshot. when you PUT to S3 that gets included in the file.
> corrupting it.
>
> Here is an article I found that explains how:
>
> https://medium.com/geekculture/upload-images-to-aws-s3-using-presigned-url-in-react-native-45059fe3d31b
>
> You can ignore the react native bit

Additional note from this question's author:

I never knew WebkitDisposition at the payload causes the file to be corrupt for AWS S3. So I had to add another function to emit the file Uri and continue with u/Wombarly's suggestion. Wherein I use the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719098/18373031 by Srijita for reference. (The uri variable at _handleImageChange function)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send image to you backend guy , and then he is gonna upload it to AWS Bucket , then try to send image as base64, then he is able to do whatever he needs with that.

sample code to make base64 from image

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.height = image.height
canvas.width = image.height

c.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

const base64 = canvas.toDataUrl('image/png' , 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe transforming it to base64 sure is a solution for this. However, I don't want to bother our backend guy so I didn't go through with this approach. There instead another solution I got wherein I just also answered in this question.